# Cross browser and test suite with testng

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automation, testng

I want to execute all my test cases in a single browser (I am using testng and maven to execute test cases) I implement `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite` all it is OK, but the problem is when I want to add one parameter "browser" to my testng.xml the error is:

> Parameter 'browser' is required by @Configuration on method testBeforeSuite but has not been marked @Optional or defined
>   in F:\workspace\my-app\browser.xml

I have the next testng.xml

[image]

I just want that the parameter `browser` applied for the TestConfig only and no to other test cases
I tried to modify my testng.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
  <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.mycompany.app.TestConfig"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 

  <test name="Test2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.mycompany.app.TestOrder"/>
      <class name="com.mycompany.app.TestDatabase"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

But the same error is displayed.
I looked for exclude parameter in testng but I didn't find anything
Is there any way to run a suit of test cases with parameter browser just for one test case? (just for config)

Comment: Put in the code for your beforesuite

Answer (score 0):

Guessing by the information, I'll say your `testBeforeSuite` method requires the browser parameter.
Have you tried applying the parameter to the suite instead of the test ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
Hi this is kumar.
You have declared the parameters in the testng.xml 
but u should read the parameter name and vaue in testng file.
 In testng file u have to use the @parameters annotatin .following code expalins


  public class Test
    {
      @parameters(browser)
      @Test
      public void runTest(string value)
        {
         WebDriver driver;
          if(value.equals("firefox"))
            {
             driver= new FirefoxDriver();
             }
       }
   }
```